# Creating ajax application without rendering JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

Sorry for my English - I am from Russia. 
I am a beginner Ruby on Rails 3 developer. I have to make ajax in my application, updating only part of html content. I can't use jQuery load function with neсessary element, because server generates content of all page and I need only part. Now I render json and generate html from it on the client using jQuery, but it is dirty and wrong. Creating pages with bit of HTML only for ajax in my opinion is dirty too. How can I solve my problem more beautiful? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this help

http://ruby-on-rails-tutorials.blogspot.com/2010/11/rails3-ajax-tricks-with-javascript-erb.html